# UIDynamicAnimator sequential animation

Tags: ios, uidynamicanimator

I'm trying to make buttons that pops out of a menu button (similar to the + button on Path) and using UIDynamicAnimator to animate the buttons snapping in and out. It works and the code is very simple.

```
    _animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:sender.superview];

    UIDynamicItemBehavior *resistance = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[_cartBtn, _chatBtn, _eventBtn]];
    resistance.resistance = 5.0f;
    [_animator addBehavior:resistance];

    CGFloat radius = 75;
    CGPoint target = sender.center;
    target.x += radius * cos(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(265));
    target.y += radius * sin(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(265));
    UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:_cartBtn snapToPoint:target];
    [_animator addBehavior:snapBehavior];

    target = sender.center;
    target.x += radius * cos(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(225));
    target.y += radius * sin(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(225));
    UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior2 = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:_chatBtn snapToPoint:target];
    [_animator addBehavior:snapBehavior2];

    target = sender.center;
    target.x += radius * cos(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(185));
    target.y += radius * sin(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(185));
    UISnapBehavior *snapBehavior3 = [[UISnapBehavior alloc] initWithItem:_eventBtn snapToPoint:target];
    [_animator addBehavior:snapBehavior3];
```

With that, all three buttons pops out together. What I'm asking if it's possible to make the buttons animate out *one after another* using UIDynamicAnimator, or something else but as simple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I just need to add a tiny delay like `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.1]];` between `addBehavior:`